# Rigify or my own armature squeeshing my mesh instead of articulating it

Tags: rigging, armature

I have used the basic human meta-rig on this human model of my own and have this problem:

I try to move just the left glove away from the body and the result is that the hand is deformed and the body next to it as well. The first picture shows the model before moving the hand/glove and the second shows the result of the move. I then tried to build my own armature but the result is the same.

[image: Model before the move]
[image]

Comment: Check and fix your mesh's normals.

Comment: [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: I think @Nathan is right. To fix the normals, select your mesh, Edit Mode, select all vertices, and press Shift N. That will most likely fix the normals (although it's not guaranteed).

Comment: I just tried fixing the normals but the problem persists. My next try is going to edit the weight painting done by Rigify. Thanks for the input